# Viper mode in all modes

Tags: emacs, viper, viper-mode, vimpulse

I'm moving from vi to emacs and, using viper and vimpulse, it gets pretty annoying when I `C-w C-w` to a window and cannot get back to the original one with the same command because the other buffer, which could be a help buffer, is not in the Viper mode. How can I fix this?

I tried to add other modes to the viper configuration and make them start with the viper mode on by default using hooks:

```
(add-to-list viper-vi-state-mode-list 'help-mode)
(add-hook 'help-mode (lambda () (setq viper-mode t)))
```

But none of these commands did work. In fact, the first one yielded the following error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/konrad/.emacs.d/init.el':

Wrong type argument: symbolp, (fundamental-mode ...
```

Besides the `C-w C-w`, I also miss not being able to navigate using hjkl. Isn't there a way to reuse the keybindings set by viper, instead of rebinding them again for every mode?

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for adding the hook to help-mode would look like this:

```
(add-hook 'help-mode-hook (lambda () (viper-mode t)))
```

Note the hook variable is named with "-hook", and setq doesn't work here because `viper-mode` is a command, not a variable.

You might be able to get all modes to activate viper with:

```
(add-hook 'fundamental-mode-hook (lambda () (viper-mode t)))
```

since all modes inherit from fundamental-mode.

Answer (score 4):

The error is because you neglected to quote the variable `viper-vi-state-mode-list` like so:

```
(add-to-list 'viper-vi-state-mode-list 'help-mode)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780838/difference-between-symbol-and-variable-name-in-emacs-lisp) as to why you need to quote `'viper-vi-state-mode-list`.

But, that didn't solve the problem for me, this is how I got <kbd>C-w C-w</kbd> to work the way you want:

```
(define-key help-mode-map (kbd "C-w C-w") 'vimpulse-cycle-windows)
```

Comment: shouldn't there be a link in "See this question .."?

Comment: The link was on the 'viper-vi-state-mode-list, I aded another link that's the intuitive one.