# Enable viper-mode when I open a file in Octave mode [emacs]

Tags: matlab, emacs, octave, viper-mode

I've set up my emacs so that it automatically uses Octave mode when I open a `.m` file (really I'm working on Matlab files).  I like to use `viper-mode`.
However, when I open a `.m` file, viper mode gets turned off, and I have to manually
restart it.  Is there a way to modify my configuration so that viper mode stays on?

.emacs.d/init.el:

```
(setq viper-mode t)
(require 'viper)

(require 'vista-c-style)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'vista-set-c-style)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.h" . c++-mode)) ;; open .h files in c++ mode


;; octave mode
(autoload 'octave-mode "octave-mod" nil t)
(setq auto-mode-alist
  (cons '("\\.m$" . octave-mode) auto-mode-alist) )

;; other config (relate to org-mode) and definition of 'vista-c-style are snipped
```

Comment: Rather than the setq+require dance, you should just use `(viper-mode 1)`.  You might also want to remove the `autoload` since it's unneeded currently and will be wrong in Emacs-24.4. where the file was renamed to `octave.el`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
(add-to-list 'viper-vi-state-mode-list 'octave-mode)
```

adapted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855890/viper-mode-in-all-modes?rq=1) worked.